# How to handle cookies with Zend_Rest_Client?

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework

I have been using Curl for making network calls and I can use the COOKIEJAR option to use cookies for my requests.

Recently I've started using Zend_REST_Client, I am not sure, how to do this? Can some one show what's the best way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Http_Client can handle cookie jar using Zend_Http_CookieJar. I think Zend_REST_Client relies on Zend_Http_Client, so you should be able to use a cookie jar.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$cookieJar = new Zend_Http_CookieJar();
$client->setCookieJar($cookieJar);
Zend_Rest_Client::setHttpClient($httpClient);
```